# Difference between $A = \{ 1,4,9\}$ and $B = \{ n^2 | n \in \{1,2,3\} \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So as stated in the question I'm confused by some basic set theory and its notation.

As I understand it there should be a difference between $A = \{1,4,9\}$ and $B = \{n^2 | n \in \{1,2,3\}\}$ because $b \in B \iff b = n^2$ and $n \in \{1,2,3\}$. Whereas if $a\in A$ it does not (have to) mean that $a=n^2$ where $n \in \{1,2,3\}$. Is this correct?

Yet it seems to me the elements of $B$, if I ignore the predicate, are the same as the elements of $A$. So does that mean that specifying a set by only listing its elements (without predicate) is insufficient? I am confused.

Comment: There is no difference between $A$ and $B$. If $a \in A$ then $a$ is one of $1,4,9$ and each is the square of $1,2,3$ and so are elements of $B$.

Comment: @IrvingRabin  But for example $4$ is also the square of $-2$. So a predicate is simply a tool to determine elements of the set, but it's not a condition for an object to be an element of the set?

Comment: The predicates should be if-and-only-if. I’m not sure what you are saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does that mean that specifying a set by only listing its elements
> (without predicate) is insufficient?

When it comes to defining any particular set, we are only concerned with the elements that set contains. Not how those elements come to be.

As long as the specification or definition accurately gives us each and every element of the set - no more, no less - the definition is sufficient.

In your example above, there is no way to end up with different elements no matter which definition you choose. Hence, they are equally sufficient and valid definitions of the sets.

Comment: Yes, I think now it's clearer. I got confused when starting to think about surjective functions. What I mean is that if I have a function such that $f(A) = f(B)$ with $A \cap B = \varnothing$, and let's say $y \in f(A)$ and thus $y \in f(B)$ then I first wrote $y = f(x)$ and $x \in A$ and also $y = f(x)$ and $x \in B$ which confused me as I was thinking $x$ is the same. What I should have written is of course $y = f(a)$ and $a \in A$ and $y = f(b)$ and $b \in B$ which is no contradiction at all. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: It can be confusing, no doubt. You asked a good question. Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Two sets are equal if they have the same elements.  Period.

It does not matter if some thinking brain came up with a definition to get the elements or whether the elements just happened to be same. If they have the same elements the sets are equal.

If we had a set $\{Alvin, Alex, Alice\}$ and Sam says "yes, those are only three people in my math class that begin with A" (and that happens to be true) and Mark says "yes, those are the three people who beat me up and demanded I give them my lunch money" (and that happens to be true).  Then

$\{Alvin, Alex, Alice\} = \{x \in \text {Sam's math class}|x\text{'s first letter is A}\} = \{z|z\text{ beat up Mark and took his lunch money}\}$

even though there is no *reason* for those identifications should be the way they just happen to be.  But they *are* and the sets are exactly the same.

$B = \{n^2|n\in \{1,2,3\}\}= \{w|w=1^2, 2^2,\text{or } 3^2\}=\{w|w=1,4,\text{ or }9\} = \{1,4,9\}$.

It's true that maybe you didn't pick $A$ specifically so they happen to be the first three squares.  But they *are*.  And that's just the way the universe is.

As $A$ and $B$ have the same elements so they are the same set.  Period.  End of story.

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that we often abuse our notation for sets in a way that hides some of the logical structure.

Before going into that, I should say (as others have) that it is fundamental in set theory that a set is determined by its elements: if $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A = B$ iff for all $x$, $x \in A$ iff $x \in B$. This does mean that if $A$ is given by set comprehension notation: $A = \{x \in X \mid \phi(x)\}$ for some set $X$ and predicate $\phi(x)$ on the elements of $X$, then $A$ is uniquely determined by $X$ and $\phi$. However, different $X$ and $\phi$ can determine the same $A$.

But worse, we often abuse the set comprehension notation and write things like $\{n^2 \mid n \in \{1, 2, 3\}\}$ (as in your example) as a short-hand for $\{m \in \Bbb{Z} \mid \exists n \in \{1, 2, 3\} \cdot m = n^2\}$. I think it is this abuse of notation that is causing your confusion: it made you misunderstand the precise condition for membership of $B$: it should be $b \in B \Leftrightarrow (\exists n \in \Bbb{Z}\cdot b = n^2 \land n \in \{1, 2, 3\})$. We can prove that this is equivalent to $b \in \{1, 4, 9\}$.

Comment: +1. Thank you. If I could accept an answer twice I would. Yes, the $\exists$ makes it much clearer!

Comment: Not to worry, Frido. As an aside, you can switch ticks from one answer to another, but please don't do so on this occasion, as @Haris's answer nails the main point down and is less boring than mine $\ddot{\smile}$

Answer (score 1):

$$x \in A \iff x \in B \iff (n\in \{1,2,3\} \; x=n^2)$$

and therefore

$$x \in A \iff (n\in \{1,2,3\} \; x=n^2)$$

Predicates can be equivalent in specific domain of discourse, even if they look different. For a simple example, $7-1=6=5+1$ these are all the same number, even though they look dissimilar.

Does this make sense?

Comment: The formulas involving $n$ in your answer aren't well-formed. Have a look at my answer for how the notation here is a short-hand for an formula involving existential quantification.